# Is an odd function differentiable at zero if it is differentiable elsewhere (and has no vertical tangent)?

Tags: calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be an odd function that is differentiable everywhere except possibly at $x = 0$. Suppose that $f$ does not have a vertical tangent at $x = 0$ (so, an example like $y = x^{1/3}$ doesn't count). Does it follow that $f$ is differentiable at zero?

If that is true, how about if we weaken the hypothesis of differentiability on $\mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$ to just continuity on $\mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$?

Edit: I meant to assume that the function is also continuous at $0$.

Comment: You defined $f$ as a function that is not differentiable at $x=0$, then you proceed to ask whether $f$ is or is not differentiable at $x=0$.  Is the answer not simply "no"?

Comment: @AndrewChin I have edited my question.

Comment: Consider the function $x\mapsto x\sin(1/x)=:f(x)$ for $x\not=0$ with $f(0):=0$.

Comment: @JensSchwaiger: You should take $|x|\sin(1/x)$ so that it’s odd; your function is even.

Comment: Of course, you should add an assumption of continuity at $0$ (it’s not enough, but it is clear you can have a function that is odd but not continuous at $0$, and then it won’t be differentiable).

Comment: If the function is meant to be continuous at $0$, "weaken the hypothesis to just continuity on $\mathbb R \setminus\{0\}$" does not make sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I’ll assume you want to ask the function to be continuous at $0$; otherwise, the example by @player3236 gives a counterexample because the lack of continuity at $0$ messes you up even before you get started.

Let $f(x)$ be defined by
$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
|x|\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) &\text{if }x\neq 0,\\
0&\text{if }x=0.
\end{array}\right.$$
Then for any $x\neq 0$ we have
$$f(-x) = |-x|\sin\left(\frac{1}{-x}\right) = -|x|\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = -f(x),$$
so $f$ is odd. It is also differentiable everywhere other than $0$, and is continuous at $0$. However,
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0^+}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
does not exist, so it does not have a derivative at $x=0$.

Comment: @twosigma: I’m taking the limit from the right, so I don’t have to take the sign of $x$; please double check “corrections” before making them to other people’s posts.

Comment: Ok. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: consider $\operatorname{sgn}(x) := \begin{cases}1 &\text{for } x > 0\\0 &\text{for } x = 0\\-1 &\text{for } x < 0\end{cases}$.